# loop images with jcoverflip

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

anyone knows how to loop images within a jcoverflip carousel into a continuous loop?
I've tryed manipulating the dom buf ofcourse it doesn't work :P

any idea? the documentation is very poor and i didn't find much on google

Comment: press CTRL+W ... sorry felt like having fun

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether or not the carousel is on the last item, and if it is you can use the following method described in their documentation.

```
first([callback], [originalEvent={}])   
Move the current to the start.

callback: a function to get called
originalEvent: the originating event object
```

You would get the current carousel position by using the `current` method, also described in the docs.

```
current([newCurrent, [originalEvent]])
Get the current item index if no parameters are passed. If newCurrent is passed, then it will move the current item to the index.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this I think.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#flip').jcoverflip({ current: 1 });

        $('.next').click(function(){

             $('#flip').jcoverflip('next', '1', true);
        });

        $('.prev').click(function(){

             $('#flip').jcoverflip('previous', '1', true);
        });
    });
```

This works perfectly for me - hope that helped. The API is truely terrible on the jcoverflip site.

Comment: I'm being dumb - I've solved another question. Useful nonetheless.